# Exact center of current sampling texel

Tags: opengl-es, texture-mapping, render-to-texture

I read that if we are sampling at exact texel center; then GL_NEAREST and GL_LINEAR sampling will give same results.
Trying to find out how.

p0  p1  p2

p3  p4  p5

p6  p7  p8

Suppose p4 is my current sampling texel. If using GL_NEAREST, it is supposed to find texel with center closest to current texel.
 If my sampling point is exactly at center of p4; will it give average of p1,p3,p5 and p7 for GL_NEAREST which is exactly the same as in GL_LINEAR ?

Is it how GL_NEAREST and GL_LINEAR becomes identical ?

Is yes, then I want to access the exact center of my current texel p4 to get same results for GL_NEAREST and GL_LINEAR. How to find exact center of current texel

Answer (score 1):

> Is it how GL_NEAREST and GL_LINEAR becomes identical ?

The idealized sample point will mathematically fall at some point between four idealized texel points. The GL_LINEAR filter returns the weighted average of the four texels based on the distance between each texel and the actual sample coordinate.

If the point is exactly over the top of one sample point, then the weight of the other three should be zero.

> How to find exact center of current texel

Hard question to answer - it depends on the triangles you are submitting, how they are laid out on screen, and the texture size you are rendering. There is no such thing as "the current texel".

If you really do just want an exact 1:1 copy you could also just use glBlitFramebuffer or something like that ...